# How can i display a UIAlertview On bottom portion of iphone?

Tags: iphone

usually the UIAlertview appear at middle of iphone screen but i want to display it bottom of iphone.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can change a `UIAlertView`'s position like so:

```
UIAlertView * alert = [ [ UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Alert" 
                        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil ];
alert.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate( alert.transform, 0.0, 100.0 );
[ alert show ];
```

You can see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039971/can-i-move-a-uialertview).